# .htaccess file rewriting more than it should

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My .htaccess file in my PHP application is supposed to redirect all requests from `example.com/playlists/[ID]` to `example.com/playlists/display.php?id=[ID]`, but the .htaccess file is also affecting other files as well. The .htaccess system is appending `/?id=edit` to the end of `example.com/playlists/edit` which is affecting the way that the page is displayed.

My directory structure:

```
Playlists
|-- index.php
`-- playlists
    |-- index.php
    |-- display.php <----------------[ THIS FILE TAKES THE .HTACCESS REDIRECTED REQUESTS ]----------------
    |-- .htaccess <----------------[ THIS IS THE PROBLEM FILE ]-------------------
    `-- edit
        `-- index.php
```

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+]+)$ display.php?id=$1
```

The only part of any URL that I want to redirect is the part after `example.com/playlists/` and nothing else, ensuring that the rules are not applied to anything else and do not override any existing directories or files.

The URL `example.com/playlists/foobar` is already being successfully rewritten to `example.com/playlists/display.php?id=foobar`.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .htaccess file is taking the edit as an id for display.php.

You need to specify that you want the edit to go to the folder specifically first, otherwise, use the original rule.

You could move the folder to the root directory and use this:

```
RewriteRule ^edit/?$ edit/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\+]+)/?$ display.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It would be `index.php`, and put the `L` flag to both of them

Comment: Thanks for catching that, and yes, the `L` is perfect specifying that they are the last rule to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped heaps.